RenderBox was not laid out Child:Listview
im making a listview has TopPostCard(), and some texts
but when i write TopPostCard(), normally i have an error BoxConstraints forces an infinite width. RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#466db relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize' 
and nothing shows just a white screen :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:realestate/screen/categorylistitem.dart';
import 'package:realestate/screen/topPostCard.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade100,
        elevation: 1,
        actions: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 150,
            height: 50,
            child: TextField(
              decoration:
              InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Search",
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          TopPostCard(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SizedBox(child: Text('Categories:',style:
            TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontFamily: 'LALUNA'
            ),
            ),),
          ),
          CategoryListItem(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Real estate posts:', style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 25.0,
                fontFamily: 'LALUNA'
            ),),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
}


and this the topPostCard :
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
class TopPostCard extends StatefulWidget {
  const TopPostCard({super.key});

  @override
  State<TopPostCard> createState() => _TopPostCardState();
}

class _TopPostCardState extends State<TopPostCard> {
 List postData=[];
  Future showAllPost()async{
    var url="";
    var response=await http.get(Uri.parse(url),headers: {"Accept":"application/json"} );
    if(response.statusCode==200){
      var jsonData=json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
     postData=jsonData;
      });
    }
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showAllPost();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: postData.length ,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(postData[index]['title']),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}


i tried a solution where they say :
i need to sizebox the listview and give it a height
or expanded it
but its still the same just a white screen and same error

wrap it with an Expanded widget inside a Row or Column this may work i guess.
